# Programmatically Cancel Control Initialisation

Tags: asp.net, ascx

Suppose I have a user control MyControl.ascx, and I put it in the Default.aspx like this:

```
<uc1:MyControl id="MyControl" runat="server">
```

Now in the code-behind of Default.aspx I do this:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    MyControl.Visible = false;
}
```

The problem is that even I do not render MyControl, it is still being initialised and goes through the entire ASCX life cycle (OnLoad, etc). Is there a way to prevent the control from being initialised at all?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't add it in the first place?

Comment: ... Which means I have to add the control dynamically in the code behind only when I need it. Makes sense. Thanks. Still, is there a way to do it once you already have the control in your markup?

Comment: You could try and remove it from the control stack of the parent control (default page) before its children are initialized.

Comment: niaher: I don't think so; I had a very quick look if you can 'Cancel' the event, but it doesn't seem that you can. I suspect you could implement some things in the control itself so that it determines if it is 'Visible', or not, and if so doesn't do various things.

Comment: Thanks silky. I will go with your initial advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding it to aspx better add it to a Placeholder from code behind dynamically. This would allow you to initialise it when you require.

Happy coding.